# Can I specify an assets to display images

Tags: ios

I want to display different images by localization, can I get an image asset with a key?

Now I'm using images in different path to do this, appending localized key to specify images path by localization.

Do you have any good ideal? Thanks!

Comment: Would be nice to show what you have tried or in this case ideas you have had as it allows people to believe you are not asking for the code on a plate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set localization for your images from the file inspector;

[image]